# How to save bash_aliases profile when provisioning vagrant?

Tags: bash, vagrant, laravel-5.1, virtual-machine, homestead

I am running `Laravel's Homestead` platform, with a `Vagrant` virtual machine. I have a `bash_aliases` file that has some custom aliases I would like to keep, however whenever I'm setting up a new project, it seems as though it gets erased back to default when you provision the machine. I would like to know how to get around this problem. I'm not sure if it's relevant, but I'm running macOS Sierra on a MacBook Pro.

Comment: Are you actually sourcing `bash_aliases`? It's not a standard `bash` configuration file.

Comment: @AndrewFox If you `man bash` you get a rather long help. Somewhere in this help is described which script files are processed at start-up and where personal additions can be made. Edit: It's actually near the beginning - in chapter `INVOCATION`.

Comment: @chepner There is a `bash_aliases` file, maybe it's part of Vagrant?

Comment: Usually, a system-supplied file like `/etc/profile` or a default version of `~/.bash_profile` contains a line like `source ~/.bash_aliases`. It's just a conventional name for a file intended to contain alias definitions.